# Difference in calculating mean AUC using Scikit-Learn

Tags: python, numpy, machine-learning, scikit-learn, cross-validation

I have the following code:

```
from sklearn import svm, datasets
from sklearn.metrics import roc_curve, auc
from sklearn.model_selection import StratifiedKFold, cross_val_score
import numpy as np
from scipy import interp

seed = 7
np.random.seed(seed)

iris = datasets.load_iris()
X = iris.data
y = iris.target
X, y = X[y != 2], y[y != 2]
n_samples, n_features = X.shape

# Add noisy features
random_state = np.random.RandomState(0)
X = np.c_[X, random_state.randn(n_samples, 200 * n_features)]

cv = StratifiedKFold(n_splits=10)
classifier = svm.SVC(kernel='linear', probability=True, random_state=seed)

mean_tpr = 0.0
mean_fpr = np.linspace(0, 1, 100)

i= 0
for train, test in cv.split(X, y):
    probas_ = classifier.fit(X[train], y[train]).predict_proba(X[test])
    # Compute ROC curve and area the curve
    fpr, tpr, thresholds = roc_curve(y[test], probas_[:, 1])
    mean_tpr += interp(mean_fpr, fpr, tpr)
    mean_tpr[0] = 0.0
    roc_auc = auc(fpr, tpr)

    i += 1


mean_tpr /= cv.get_n_splits(X, y)
mean_tpr[-1] = 1.0
mean_auc_1 = auc(mean_fpr, mean_tpr)
print "#--- Method 1 to calculate mean AUC ---"
print mean_auc_1


print "#--- Method 2 to calculate mean AUC ---"
results = cross_val_score(classifier, X, y, cv=cv)
mean_auc_2 =  "{:.3f}".format(results.mean())
print mean_auc_2
```

It produces the following result:

```
#--- Method 1 to calculate mean AUC ---
0.801818181818
#--- Method 2 to calculate mean AUC ---
0.700
```

Method 1 of calculating mean AUC is through loop as suggested by **[this Scikit Tutorial](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/model_selection/plot_roc_crossval.html#sphx-glr-auto-examples-model-selection-plot-roc-crossval-py)**.
Method 2 calculates the mean AUC using Scikit's inbuilt **[cross_val_score()](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.cross_val_score.html)** method.

My question is, why the difference? Which mean AUC should I believe?
How should I modify Method 2 so that the result is the same with Method 1?

I'm using this version of Scikit-Learn:

```
In [442]: sklearn.__version__
Out[442]: '0.18'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no auc calculation for your second example.
You should add a custom scoring function. See the api for [cross_val_score](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.cross_val_score.html).

You are just calculating the average accuracy. This is typically the standard scoring function used for a [classifier](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/model_evaluation.html). You can check the standard score function for the svm in the [documentation](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.svm.SVC.html#sklearn.svm.SVC)

Something like this

```
cross_val_score(classifier, X, y, cv=cv, scoring='roc_auc')
```

should work

Comment: Thanks. Can you give example code? How should I modify Method 2 so that the result is the same with Method 1?

Comment: That is what they do in the first method

Comment: @MMF: so use Method 1 instead of Method 2?

Comment: If you want the AUC yes

Comment: @neversaint, no it's not necessary. You can define a custom scoring function or use the option in my updated example.

Comment: @Quickbeam2k1: I tried, there's still a little bit difference `In [32]: cross_val_score(classifier, X, y, cv=cv,scoring='roc_auc').mean()
Out[32]: 0.80400000000000005`

Comment: I'm having the same difference.when you uncomment `mean_tpr[0] = 0.0` you get 0.80444444 which is closer. Potentially, there are some minor issues in the code around the for loop

Comment: @Quickbeam2k1: In my OP method 2 example what values does *plain* `cross_val_score(classifier, X, y, cv=cv)` gives? I can't find the right documentation.

Comment: check my answer: you are calculating accuracy, which is the standard metric for classifiers.